# Vite Rollup failed to resolve import (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, build, vite

I have a problem while building my Vite React App with Docker.

I always get this error.

```
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@/pages/Private" from "/app/src/Main.tsx"
```

But when I build it localy everything works fine. I have a feeling that its related with the tsconfig.

tsconfig.json:

```json
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "paths": {
          "@/*": ["*"]
        }
      },
      "include": ["src/**/*"],
      "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
    }
```

vite.config.ts:

```
import { URL, fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    build: {
      outDir: './build',
      rollupOptions: {
        external: './src',
      },
    },
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
  };
});
```

Project structure:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── Main.tsx
│   └── pages
│       └── Private.tsx
├── vite.config.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21.2.0-alpine3.18 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY .npmrc ./
COPY src src/
COPY public public/
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY tailwind.config.js ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY postcss.config.js ./
COPY index.html ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm run build
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I came to an solution

I forgot to add the `vite.config.ts` to the `Dockerfile`

`COPY vite.config.ts ./` fixed it.